# understanding data structures in perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to understand the 'Common Mistake' section in the perldsc documentation. What is the author trying to convey when he mentions:

> The two most common mistakes made in constructing something like an array of arrays is either accidentally counting the number of elements or else taking a reference to the same memory location repeatedly. Here's the case where you just get the count instead of a nested array:

```
for my $i (1..10) {
    my @array = somefunc($i);
    $AoA[$i] = @array;      # WRONG!
}
```

From what I understand is that when it iterate it will take the first value of (1..10) which is 1 and will pass it to a function like this:

```
my @array = somefunc(1);
```

Since that function is not defined, I'll create the logic.

```
sub somefunc  {
my $a = shift;
print $a * $a;
}
```

which will essentially do this:

```
1 * 1
```

and the result is '1'.

To my understanding   my @array will look like:

```
@array = ('1');
```

And the next line will do:

```
$AoA[$i] = @array;
```

I'm assuming that $AoA[$1] is an anonymous array ( he/she didn't declare with 'my', btw) and the @array will be the first element of the this anonymous array which the author said it' WRONG. And the for each loop with iterate to '2'.

```
somefunc(2);
```

Which will be '4' and passed to:

```
$AoA[$i] = @array
```

What is the point of the author with this code which is wrong. I'm trying to understand what is wrong but more importantly, I'm trying to understand the code. Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE

I think I understand why this is a common mistake because when I use print and Dumper, I can visually see what the author is trying to convey, here is the revised code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

for my $i (1..10) {
           my @AoA;
           my @array = somefunc($i);
           print "The array is Dumper(@array)\n";
           $AoA[$i] = @array;      # WRONG!
           print Dumper($AoA[$i]);
       }


sub somefunc  {
my $a = shift;
return $a * $a;
}
```

In the Common Mistakes paragraph of perldoc perldsc, he/she states

> Here's the case where you just get the count instead of a nested array:

Below is the output of the Dumper.

```
The array is Dumper(1)
$VAR1 = 1;
The array is Dumper(4)
$VAR1 = 1;
The array is Dumper(9)
$VAR1 = 1;
The array is Dumper(16)
$VAR1 = 1;
The array is Dumper(25)
$VAR1 = 1;
The array is Dumper(36)
$VAR1 = 1;
The array is Dumper(49)
$VAR1 = 1;
The array is Dumper(64)
$VAR1 = 1;
The array is Dumper(81)
$VAR1 = 1;
The array is Dumper(100)
$VAR1 = 1;
```

So I'm assuming that the repeated

```
$VAR1 = 1;
```

is the count and not the nested array.

The author did indicate that if the count is what I truly want then to rewrite the code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

for my $i (1..10) {
           my @count;
           my @array = somefunc($i);
           print "The array is Dumper(@array)\n";
           $count[$i] = scalar @array;      
           print Dumper($count[$i]);
       }


sub somefunc  {
my $a = shift;
return $a * $a;
}
```

But the documentation didn't tell me how to get the nested array?

UPDATE

Correct me if I am wrong but I rewrote the code to get the nested array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my @count;
my @new_array;

for my $i (1..10) {
           #my @count;
           my @array = somefunc($i);
           push @new_array, [@array];
       }


sub somefunc  {
my $a = shift;
return $a * $a;
}

print Dumper(\@new_array);
```

Which printed

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        1
      ],
      [
        4
      ],
      [
        9
      ],
      [
        16
      ],
      [
        25
      ],
      [
        36
      ],
      [
        49
      ],
      [
        64
      ],
      [
        81
      ],
      [
        100
      ]
    ];
```

Comment: I think that should be `return $a * $a` and not `print $a * $a` ? And `$AoA[$i]` refers to the `$i`th element of the regular array `@AoA` (which the author did not declare). The assignment `$AoA[$i] = @array` is in scalar context so `@array` will evaluate to the length of the array

Comment: Re "*@array will be the first element of the this anonymous array*", No, `@array` in scalar context evaluates to the number of elements inside of `@array`.

Comment: Note that the example is trying to demonstrate how to place `@array` inside an element of `@AoA`, so `sub somefunc { my $i = shift; return ( $i*2, $i*3 ); }` would serve as a better example.

Comment: "the documentation didn't tell me how to get the nested array". But many of our answers did. `$AoA[$i] = \@array;`. Use Dumper to print `@AOA` and see what you get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the following statement:

```
$AoA[$i] = @array;
```

the `@array` is referenced in a *scalar context*, yielding a number of its elements. The context is imposed by LHS, that is `$AoA[$i]` which is a single element of the `@AoA` array.

In Perl, there are no array of arrays in a strict sense. These are emulated essentially by either "flatten" arrays or array with references. For the latter, you would need to use take reference operator as in:

```
$AoA[$i] = \@array;
```

For the starter, you may find, that [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) is very handy in examining complex data stuctures such as arrayrefs and hashrefs.

Answer (score 1):

Perl is polymorphic, which means that it deals with different data types transparently, and makes what is usually a pretty good guess on how to deal with something. This makes the programmer's work much easier because it is not strongly typed like other languages.

So for example if $i is the number 4, you can do this:

```
print $i + 1;
```

and you will see a 5 - pretty logical, right?

and if you do this:

```
print "I am " , $i , " years old";
```

You will see "I am 4 years old" - in this case perl says "you are operating in list context, so I will treat $i as a string. No need to convert the number into a string as many other languages insist.

So when you assign

```
$AoA[$i] = @array;
```

The way it treats this depends on the context. In scalar context, it will set $AoA[$i] to be the length of the array.

For more information about scalar vs list context, read this answer:

http://perl.plover.com/context.html

Comment: Good point, too much time spent in javascript. Should have used the "." operator, but then it's explicitly doing concatenation :)

Comment: "you are operating in list context, so I will treat $i as a string". List context says nothing about whether a value is treated as a number or a string. It's `print()` that is converting all of its arguments to strings. If you replaced the commas with dots, then `$i` would be evaluated in scalar context, but would still be converted to a string (this time, by the concatenation operator rather than by `print()`).

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't very useful in understanding what is going on here as your subroutine always returns "1" - the result of calling `print()`. If you replace the `print()` with `return()` then you will at get different values (1, 4, 9, etc).

But the next line of code:

```
$AoA[$i] = @array;
```

Will always assign `1` to the element of `@Aoa`. That's because You are assigning an array (`@array`) to a scalar variable (`$AoA[$i]`) and when you evaluate an array in a scalar context, you get the number of elements in the array.

Now, as your `@array` only ever has a single element, you could do this:

```
$AoA[$i] = $array[0];
```

But that's not really building an array of arrays. What you really want to do is to get a reference to an array.

```
$AoA[$i] = \@array;
```

This would be more useful if your subroutine returned more than one value.

```
sub somefunc  {
  # Used $x instead of $a as $a has a special meaning in Perl
  my $x = shift;
  return ($x * $x, $x * $x * $x);
}

for my $i (1..10) {
  my @array = somefunc($i);
  $AoA[$i] = \@array;
}
```

As useful tool for exploring this is [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper). Try adding:

```
use Data::Dumper;
```

To the top of your code and:

```
print Dumper @AoA;
```

After the `foreach` loop to see the different data structures that you get back.